# Разбить переменную на несколько

Tags: perl

Как в Perl разбить переменную на несколько по 2 цифры в каждой.

Например:

Исходная переменная 2345, получаем 23 и 45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

my $var='1234567890';

my (@vars)=$var=~/\d{2}/g;

print Dumper @vars;
```

Dumper - лишь для визуализации ответа. Результат лежит в массиве vars, vars[0] - первые 2 числа, vars[1] - вторые и т.д..

Результат

```
$VAR1 = '12';
$VAR2 = '34';
$VAR3 = '56';
$VAR4 = '78';
$VAR5 = '90';
```

убрав Дампер получите проще..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $var='1234567890';
my (@vars)=$var=~/\d{2}/g;
print join "\n",@vars;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! работает!

Comment: @Антон Черепков, не надо спешить. Уберите нолик из примера `$var='123456789';` и посмотрите, что получилось.

И не забывайте, что на perl'е сделать ошибку не легко, а очень легко.

Answer (score 1):

В Perl для этого нет(хотя может есть на CPAN) каких-либо особых функций. Так что предлагаю использовать [substr()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)

Например:

```
my $int = 2345;
print substr($int, -2); //45
print substr($int, 0, -2); //23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $n = 8491823412432341234;
my @d = unpack('(a2)*', $n);
print join("\n", @d);
```